# Electron Menus and Project Structure

Tags: node.js, menu, electron

Bit of a newbie with Electron and learning from some YouTube vids and a Udemy course.

I have a couple of sample apps up and running - so far so good, but my question is this:

Now that I'm starting to consider the design/structure I would use for a much larger, more meaningful application I want to move all my Menus into a source folder like 'menuTemplates' and in that folder I would probably need between 10-15 different menu structures to be stored.

Inside each file I would expect to be able to put structures like:

```
 {
    label: "Menu",
      submenu: [
        { 
          label: "One",
          submenu: []
        },
        {
          label: "Two",
          submenu: []
        },
        {
          label: "Quit", 
          click() {
            app.quit()
          }
        }
      ]
 }
```

In other words, I just want to put the json documents which define the menus into something like:

menuTemplates/menuMain.js

menuTemplates/browseForFileModel,js

menuTemplates/editUrl.js

Where each file contains the correct menu depending on where the user 'is' in the app and what they are trying to do.

Could someone point me in the right direction for how to achieve this? Should each of those .js files be a module? If so what and how to export the json?

I wish that Menu.buildFromTemplate() would just accept a path. That would make life so much simpler.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have very simple modules that simply export one menu template object each:

```js
// menuTemplates/menu1.js

module.exports = {
    label: "Menu",
    submenu: [
        // menu template ..
    ]
}
```

And then you can build the menu as you know it:

```
const menu1_template = require("menuTemplates/menu1.js");
const menu1 = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menu1_template);
```